# Train Spacy NER model with 'en_core_web_sm' as base model

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am using Spacy to train my NER model with new entities and I am using `en_core_web_sm` model as my base model because I also want to detect the basic entities (`ORG`, `PERSON`, `DATE`, etc). I ran `en_core_web_sm` model over unlabelled sentences, and adding their annotations to my training set.

After I finished with that, now I want to create the training data for the new entities. For example, I want to add a new entity called `FRUIT`. I have a bunch of sentences (in addition to those that were annotated using `en_core_web_sm` earlier) that I am going to annotate. The sentence example is:

> "James likes eating apples".

***My question is***: Do I still need to annotate "*James*" as `PERSON` as well as annotating "*apples*" as `FRUIT`? Or whether I don't need to do it because I already have another bunch of sentences that were annotated with `PERSON` entity using `en_core_web_sm` model earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Yes, if you want to keep your model precise.

**Long answer:**

NER is implemented using Machine Learning algorithms. These classify a token as a Entity based on learned distributions and surrounding tokens.

Therefore, if you provide several samples of annotated text without marking a word (token) as a specific Entity that it usually represents, you may affect your model precision by providing samples to your model where that token is unimportant.